# Set div to fill remaining screen height

Tags: html, css

Code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>
        "..."
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="searchBox">
            <table>
                "..."
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="tableData">
            <table>
                "..."
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

The `searchBox` is not important. I just put it there to show that there is something above my other table (`tableData`).

What I am trying to achieve is to get `tableData` to fill the rest of the screen height visible so no scroll bars are required.

I have researched and come across multiple solutions but none of these seem to work:

**1. Set 'vh' property**

Even though this goes off the viewport dimensions it's pretty good. However, I have a tabbed UI with all tabs having `tableData` displayed but at different positions on the page. This means that switching from tab to tab, `tableData` does not have time to render the new dimensions. Example sketch below:

[image]

So if I base the height of `tableData` on the image on the left where the content above is smaller, then the height of `tableData` will be too big and over-stretch on the other tab where the position of it has changed

**2. Using absolute positioning**

I immediately wrote this off as I also want my page to be responsive upon different devices and I understand that using absolute positioning can mess that up

**3. Flexbox**

I have been following this post for this method:
[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

I have tried this approach but it removed all of my other CSS I had on the page.

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What does "it removed all of my other CSS" mean? Did you try other answers from that question like [css tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16960823/1529630) or [`calc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23323175/1529630)?

Comment: It removed all of the other styling on my page. I have attempted that CSS approach yes and did not make a difference. I have not tried `calc()` so will attempt that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: If it removed all your css you made have made a mistake, a fiddle would help us find out what exactly happend ... I flagged this as duplicate because the answer you linked contains a lot of possiblities to solve this problem, not just flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the height of your `divs` with `%'s`, then all you have to do is set your `html` to `100%`.

Here's how to do it:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#searchBox {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

#tableData {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52ofup22/1/).

**Update**
added `margin: 0;` to `html` and `body` and updated the jsfiddle

Comment: I did try that. The `html` and `body` worked as they were supposed to (height of the screen) but `tableData` went beyond the body and over-stretched again

Comment: maybe decrease the `height` percent of the `html`?

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: actually instead of decreasing the `height` of the `html`, just add this to your css - `* { margin: 0; }`